# Unmet dependencies texlive

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, latex, texlive

I am trying to start from scratch because I messed up my installation of texlive.

When I try

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive-full
```

I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 asymptote : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: texlive-base-bin
 context : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2016)
           Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016) but 2013.20140215-1 is to be installed
           Depends: texlive-metapost (>= 2016) but 2013.20140215-1 is to be installed
           Depends: tex-common (>= 6) but 4.04 is to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-freefont but it is not installable
 dvipng : Depends: texlive-base-bin
 feynmf : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: texlive-font-utils but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
 fragmaster : Depends: texlive-base-bin
              Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: texlive-font-utils but it is not going to be installed
 latex-beamer : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
 latex-cjk-common : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: texlive-font-utils (>= 2007.dfsg.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
 latex-cjk-thai : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: texlive-lang-other (>= 2013.20130523-1) but it is not going to be installed
 latexmk : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
 prosper : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
 tex4ht : Depends: texlive-base-bin
 tex4ht-common : Depends: texlive-base-bin
 texlive-base : Depends: luatex (>= 0.70.1)
                Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016) but 2013.20140215-1 is to be installed
                           Depends: tex-common (>= 6) but 4.04 is to be installed
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016) but 2013.20140215-1 is to be installed
                                 Depends: tex-common (>= 6) but 4.04 is to be installed
 texlive-humanities-doc : Depends: tex-common (>= 6) but 4.04 is to be installed
                          Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016) but 2013.20140215-1 is to be installed
 texlive-latex-extra : Depends: luatex
                       Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
 texlive-latex-recommended : Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
 texlive-luatex : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
                  Depends: luatex (>= 0.70.1)
 texlive-math-extra : Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
 texlive-metapost : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
 texlive-music : Depends: musixtex (>= 1:0.114-2)
                 Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
                 Depends: m-tx
                 Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: luatex
                 Depends: pmx
 texlive-omega : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
                 Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
 texlive-pictures : Depends: luatex
                    Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
 texlive-pstricks : Depends: texlive-generic-recommended (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
                    Recommends: texlive-font-utils but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
 texlive-publishers : Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
 texlive-science : Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
 texlive-xetex : Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512)
 tipa : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: texlive-base-bin
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to do `sudo apt-get -f install`

But I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-inconsolata latex-sanskrit swath
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-ebgaramond
  fonts-ebgaramond-extra fonts-roboto-hinted fonts-sil-gentiumplus
  fonts-sil-gentiumplus-compact libfile-homedir-perl libkpathsea6 libosp5
  libostyle1c2 libpoppler61 libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libsynctex1 libtexlua52
  libtexluajit2 openjade prerex tex-common texlive-base texlive-bibtex-extra
  texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils texlive-fonts-extra
  texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-formats-extra texlive-games
  texlive-generic-extra texlive-generic-recommended texlive-htmlxml
  texlive-humanities texlive-lang-african texlive-lang-arabic
  texlive-lang-chinese texlive-lang-cjk texlive-lang-cyrillic
  texlive-lang-czechslovak texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-european
  texlive-lang-french texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-greek
  texlive-lang-indic texlive-lang-italian texlive-lang-japanese
  texlive-lang-korean texlive-lang-other texlive-lang-polish
  texlive-lang-portuguese texlive-lang-spanish texlive-latex-base
  texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc
  texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex
  texlive-math-extra texlive-metapost texlive-metapost-doc texlive-music
  texlive-omega texlive-pictures texlive-pictures-doc texlive-plain-extra
  texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc texlive-publishers
  texlive-publishers-doc texlive-science texlive-science-doc texlive-xetex
  ttf-adf-universalis vprerex
Suggested packages:
  perl-tk libspreadsheet-parseexcel-perl libtcltk-ruby dot2tex
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-ebgaramond
  fonts-ebgaramond-extra fonts-roboto-hinted fonts-sil-gentiumplus
  fonts-sil-gentiumplus-compact libfile-homedir-perl libosp5 libostyle1c2
  libpoppler61 libpotrace0 libsynctex1 libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 openjade
  prerex texlive-bibtex-extra texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils
  texlive-font-utils texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-recommended
  texlive-formats-extra texlive-games texlive-generic-extra
  texlive-generic-recommended texlive-htmlxml texlive-humanities
  texlive-lang-african texlive-lang-arabic texlive-lang-chinese
  texlive-lang-cjk texlive-lang-cyrillic texlive-lang-czechslovak
  texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-european texlive-lang-french
  texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-greek texlive-lang-indic
  texlive-lang-italian texlive-lang-japanese texlive-lang-korean
  texlive-lang-other texlive-lang-polish texlive-lang-portuguese
  texlive-lang-spanish texlive-latex-base ttf-adf-universalis vprerex
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libkpathsea6 libptexenc1 tex-common texlive-base texlive-latex-base-doc
  texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-latex-recommended
  texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex texlive-math-extra
  texlive-metapost texlive-metapost-doc texlive-music texlive-omega
  texlive-pictures texlive-pictures-doc texlive-plain-extra texlive-pstricks
  texlive-pstricks-doc texlive-publishers texlive-publishers-doc
  texlive-science texlive-science-doc texlive-xetex
25 upgraded, 51 newly installed, 0 to remove and 204 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,730 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,109 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: failed to open configuration file '/udd/fschiano/.dpkg.cfg' for reading: Permission denied
(Reading database ... 363781 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../texlive-latex-base-doc_2016.20160523-1~ubuntu14.04.1york0_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-latex-base-doc (2016.20160523-1~ubuntu14.04.1york0) over (2013.20140215-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-latex-base-doc_2016.20160523-1~ubuntu14.04.1york0_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/url/url.tex.gz', which is also in package texlive-latex-recommended-doc 2013.20140215-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-latex-base-doc_2016.20160523-1~ubuntu14.04.1york0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does someone can help me please?

Thanks a lot.

I tried searching on the internet but no solution worked so far :( I already spent 2 hours solving this :(